# Tikkunei Zohar in English or Hebrew

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, translation, zohar

Has the Tikunei Zohar ever been translated into English? Perhaps Hebrew? Online or dead tree works.

Answer (score 1):

Plain Hebrew translation:
https://www.greenfieldjudaica.com/tikunei-zohar-with-perush-in-loshon-kodesh-S132087.html

Hebrew translation with commentary:
https://seforimcenter.com/Rabbi-Daniel-Frisch---Matok-MiDvash-1935-2005/Tikkunei-HaZohar---Peirush-Matok-MiDvash-3-vol.__p-364-9734.aspx

Plain English translation:
[https://www.amazon.com/Tikkunei-Zohar-Revealed-English-Commentary/dp/1506134823](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1506134823)

English Translation with commentary:
[https://www.amazon.com/Tikkunei-Zohar-Revealed-English-Commentary/dp/1506134823](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1506134823)

Just to note, most, if not all English translations of kabbalah seforim are highly inaccurate and are authored by people who don't subscribe to orthodox Judaism, sometimes they aren't even Jewish at all.

The one exception I can think of is Rav Aryeh Kaplan ZT"L, I have had the privilege to learn from his talmidim and have gained tremendously from his works, I would recommend learning his works starting with [Inner Space](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0940118564).

As Bluejayke said above, it is incumbent upon a person to spend many years learning the basics of niglah, a.k.a the revealed parts of Torah like Tanach, Shas Bavli and Yerushalmi, Medrash, and Shulchan Aruch well before truly delving into the works of kabbalah head-on. If one has spent time learning these basics he won't need an English translation.

I have only learned the works that Rav Kaplan wrote on the general concepts of kabbalah which, according to Halachah, is permitted to be learned without extensive knowledge of the basics, each person should consult their Rav regarding when is the right time for him to delve into kabbalah on a legitimate level.

Answer (score 1):

At http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikunei_haZohar#External_links there are links to:

1. An anonymous translation of the Intro and Tikkunim 1 through 17.
2. en:Wikisource where there is a budding English translation project where anyone may contribute.
3. TZ with Hebrew translation.

The TZ-with-Hebrew (as well as the rest of the Zohar) found in #3 above, from ha-zohar.com, has also been arranged in a 4-up (meaning 4 per page) for concise printing on letter paper, available here: http://zohar.altervista.org/

Answer (score 0):

B"H

I don't necessarily recommend the translation, especially for people who haven't learned torah for 40 years and/or is older than 40, depending on the opinions (and I would much rather recommend actual chassidus that can be grasped by ones brain even in a simple and practical eat) but here it goes

http://files.kabbalahmedia.info/files/eng_t_ml-sefer-zohar.pdf

Blessings and success

Comment: That's the Hakdama of the Zohar

Comment: @nissim oh brutal, maybe Hashem doesn't want people who only speak English tu read tikunei Zohar then, maybe He wants them to learn other things first, such as chitas

Comment: If you think reading "nefesh habehamis this, nefesh ha'elokis that" is going to save the world, go for it.  B'hai sifra yifqun beih min galuta berachamei.  In this book [of the Zohar the Jews] will get up out of exile in a goodness.  This is especially true of the Tikkunim which being in `Asiyah is already full of pikudim for example BRASYT = TReY SBT Two Shabbats, YRA BST, Have Fear of Heaven and Humility etc. etc.

Comment: @nissim but the rebbe injured much more about the Torah than any of us do, and if he said that every soul should learn chitas, them we should probably trust him, and that statement applies equally to the chawseedis as explained by chabad, the current tanya is at one of the pretty intense parts right now, it's hawshgawcha prawteess of you start now, but I can't force anything, I'm just saying that the Rebbe, who knows much more than anyone here, says that it's something that every soul from the nation of Yisroyayl must do, even someone who never put on tefillin the Rebbe said to learn it